# Socket.io vs xmpp for a mobile chat app

Tags: ios, socket.io, xmpp

I have to build a realtime chat app in iOS, which can later also have voice and video calling. I want to use a scalable and light weight solution integrated with the backend, making sure that the solution also supports calling in the future.
I'm not too sure if socket.io supports voice and video calls; Should I use that or xmpp? Or any other similar solution?

Comment: xmpp is a protocol whereas socket.io is a realtime communication server implementation. It is like comparing a cell-phone to a network carrier. From What I know, socket.io just deals with websockets, and websockets are not good for transmitting such things as voice or video, you will need to negociate a p2p session between users (maybe that p2p session will be using webRTC) if you want to do this. If I remember well, that is what happens with xmpp jingle extension. There is a negociation on the XMPP channel before opening a p2p session for audio.

Answer (score 1):

As it was written above socket.io is a chat server implementation using Websockets, while XMPP is a protocol. 
I'd recommend using an XMPP chat server in this case. 
For audio/video calls implementation you will need to implement signaling via XMPP to establish connection between the devices before the call. 
Also for audio/video chat  implementation you will need STUN/TURN/ICE server and you will need to add client-side implementation for passing media streams from peer-to-peer if you choose WebRTC peer-to-peer option.

There is an easier way as well. You can use a ready XMPP based server and SDK to build your app. For example, [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) provides such service. 
They have a ready backend and SDKs you can use for building chat and audio/video chat apps. Also they already have a TURN server, so you do not need to worry about this part too.